# Table empty after restarting mySQL Server

Tags: mysql, triggers, restart

I got a lot of tables inside a database.
Strange thing is that one table always empties after restarting mySQL.
It seems like it's a TEMP table but i doubt that.
Where can i see if it is a TEMP table or is something else triggering this event.

Talking about triggers, I do have a trigger inside another table that updates values but i do not think that this is the cause of it.

[Edit]

**My trigger query is**

```
BEGIN
IF NEW.Discount <> OLD.Discount || NEW.Price <> OLD.Price || NEW.FirstYearDiscount <> OLD.FirstYearDiscount
THEN
INSERT INTO InvoiceTotal SET
                        PriceExcl = (SELECT
                        SUM((Price - (Price * (IF(Discount > FirstYearDiscount || Discount < 0, Discount, FirstYearDiscount) / 100))) * InvoicePeriod)
                        FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceID = NEW.InvoiceID),
                        InvoiceID = NEW.InvoiceID
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                PriceExcl = (SELECT
                        SUM((Price - (Price * (IF(Discount > FirstYearDiscount || Discount < 0, Discount, FirstYearDiscount) / 100))) * InvoicePeriod)
                        FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceID = NEW.InvoiceID);
END IF;
END
```

This trigger wil update values if change.

I also got a cronjob that inserts new values when a order is made.

Comment: My first guess would be that you load the data in a transaction and never commit the transaction.

Comment: I also insert data inside the table just like in other tables. I've build this table like any other table inside my database.

Comment: How does one go about "resetting SQL"? What does that mean? Do you mean you are restarting the MySQL server? Or are you disconnecting and connecting to the database? Are you executing some kind of SQL statement?

Comment: i mean restarting de SQL server. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging around and for each Table, clicked on `Operations` (mixed in with the tabs up top), and noticed a property called `Storage Engine`. It was initially set to **Memory**, which seemed off to me. So I checked my other databases and noticed they were all set to **MyISAM**. So I changed the tables, in the Database I was having problems with, to **MyISAM** and restarted my server to test check them. The data was now saving with no problems!

Hope it helps other people who has the same problem (Y)

PS. Thanks for the replies guys

Comment: You *probably* want InnoDB instead of MyISAM. Research more.